# How to filter using isin from another pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

`df1` has a lot of data, I want to filter that has `id` that  avaliable in `df2`. Here's what I did

```
df1.filter(col('id').isin(df2.select('id')))
```

Here's the error message,

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in isin(self, *cols)
    441         if len(cols) == 1 and isinstance(cols[0], (list, set)):
    442             cols = cols[0]
--> 443         cols = [c._jc if isinstance(c, Column) else _create_column_from_literal(c) for c in cols]
    444         sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    445         jc = getattr(self._jc, "isin")(_to_seq(sc, cols))

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    441         if len(cols) == 1 and isinstance(cols[0], (list, set)):
    442             cols = cols[0]
--> 443         cols = [c._jc if isinstance(c, Column) else _create_column_from_literal(c) for c in cols]
    444         sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    445         jc = getattr(self._jc, "isin")(_to_seq(sc, cols))

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py in _create_column_from_literal(literal)
     33 def _create_column_from_literal(literal):
     34     sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
---> 35     return sc._jvm.functions.lit(literal)
     36 
     37 

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1246 
   1247     def __call__(self, *args):
-> 1248         args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)
   1249 
   1250         command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in _build_args(self, *args)
   1216 
   1217         args_command = "".join(
-> 1218             [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
   1219 
   1220         return args_command, temp_args

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1216 
   1217         args_command = "".join(
-> 1218             [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])
   1219 
   1220         return args_command, temp_args

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_command_part(parameter, python_proxy_pool)
    296             command_part += ";" + interface
    297     else:
--> 298         command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
    299 
    300     command_part += "\n"

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.3-1.cdh7.1.3.p0.4992530/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1302         if name not in self.columns:
   1303             raise AttributeError(
-> 1304                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
   1305         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
   1306         return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Comment: You can inner join the 2 Dataframes or collect the distinct id's in a list and use it within `isin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trying this: `df1.join(df2.select('id'), ['id'], 'inner')`

Comment: If someone wonders how to do this if the columns have different names: `df1.join(df2.select('id2').withColumnRenamed('id2', 'id'), ['id'], 'inner')`.
Also, the single-element-list of columns can be replaced with just a string: `df1.join(df2.select('id'), 'id', 'inner')`. Hope someone finds this helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

`select()` returns a DataFrame:

```py
print(type(df2.select('id')))

# <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

Hence you need to convert this into a list and provide to `isin()`:

```py
df2_id_list = df2.select('id').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
df1 = df1.filter(F.col('id').isin(df2_id_list))
```

But `collect()` is not advisable as it tries to move all the selected data to the driver and the driver may go out of memory. Therefore it's better to use something like `join` with `leftsemi`. `leftsemi` helps avoid duplicate ids in df2 from being created in the final result of df1.

```py
df1 = df1.join(df2, 'id', 'leftsemi')
```

Comment: note -- `collect()` does not move **all the data**, only the selected/processed data.

Comment: @samkart, sorry for the misunderstanding, that's what I meant. The data that `collect()` is called upon. Thanks for pointing out, will make it clearer in the answer.